# Is there a way to route different vehicles within OSM2PO? 

Tags: routing, osm2po

Is there a way to route different vehicles within OSM2PO? I would like to start the service with a config file and then turn different flags on/off depending on whether the route is for a bike or a car or a pedestrian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**. But this decision has to be made dynamically. Meaning, you'll have to overwrite the DefaultRouter or alternatively implement one from scratch.

Let's prefer the first approach:

- Overwrite traverse(...) in order to get a reference to the Graph-Object.
  (do not forget to delegate to super.traverse() at the end)
- Overwrite calcEdgeCost(int index)
  The index-parameter points to the current edge while traversing.
  normally calcEdgeCost returns either
  graph.getEdgeCostsKm()[index] or graph.getEdgeCostsH()[index]
- The road type is accessible via
  graph.getEdgeFlags()[index]
  which returns the configured classId (e.g. 21 == Secondary)
- If you need more Properties, you might want to overwrite
  DefaultBuildInterceptor or implement another GraphBuildInterceptor.
- car/bike/foot can be set in the Properties argument of traverse() before
  each call.
- Alernatively you can implement one Router per UseCase
- or even one Graph per UseCase
- or even both.

Comment: This is perfect. I'll give your first approach a try and get back to you. Thanks for your help friend!

Comment: I've been playing around with the .config file to try and get some different results. I basically created a route with the default config and checked the geojson result for time and distance. Then I stopped the service and changed the .config marking all the tag.highway.xxx with 5 as the default speed and changed wtr.finalMask to bike. I restarted the service and checked the route with the geojson response. I got the exact same result with the same time and distance. Any thoughts? How do I edit the .config file to use with different vehicles?

Comment: On my above comment, you have to modify the .config file then rebuild the graph. The wtr tags that were modified will then be implemented by the service.

Comment: You do not need to modify the speed because you can use shortest path instead of fastest. This should give you the same results.

Comment: Thanks Carsten, I modified the default speed to get more accurate "Time" calculations in the GeoJSON response. However, I found that roads with a maxspeed tag in the OSM data took precedence over my modified default speeds in the .config file. Is there a way to ensure the default speeds are used. Since I am creating a walking route with a 5 kmh default speed, roads with a maxspeed tag (and a value of 80 kmh) in the OSM data are giving me faulty speeds/times for a walking pace. Of course I guess I could just code for this result if necessary.

Comment: Hmm... if you use a constant speed for each way-type, so what do you need the speed value for anyway? Just take the length [km] instead and divide it by 5km/h to get the time in [h].

Comment: Exactly, that was my workaround. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: No problem. If you like, you may contact me on info@osm2po.de for more help.

Comment: The maxspeed issue has been fixed in the current version (4.6.9) . Now there's a new parameter called maxSpeedOverrides which can be set to false.