# finding routes just for cyclists

Tags: pgrouting, osm2po

I have created a PostGIS DB using osm2po and I am using pgrouting to calculate the routes.

The application I am creating should find routes for cyclists so I want the route finder to prefer roads with cycle lanes present and to never plot a route containing motorways.

Looking through the config files I see: `wrt.finalMask` = car along with other tags such `wtr.tag.highway.motorway = 1, 11, 120, car`

I was wondering are these the parameters that I should tweak to accomplish this?

Would I just remove tags such as motorway etc.?

Thanks

Comment: Answer is here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41286/how-to-control-what-kind-of-tags-flags-are-imported-with-osm2po

Comment: and here http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29342/is-there-a-way-to-route-different-vehicles-within-osm2po User Carsten is the knowledge based on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy. Let's regard these lines:

```
wtr.tag.highway.secondary_link = 1, 22, 30,  car
wtr.tag.highway.tertiary = 1, 31, 40,  car|bike
```

Setting

```
wtr.finalMask = car
```

imports both road types,

setting

```
wtr.finalMask = bike
```

imports the tertiary road only.

Actually `car|bike` are values (1+2=3) in the flags-column.
It's derived from the `wtr.flagList = car, bike, foot ...`
where car=1, bike=2, foot=4 and so on.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot that works well.

Just one question. Would it be possible for me to add a custom tag such as 'difficulty' to the OSM data in my database and then have osm2po calculate the costs based on the difficulty of a way from 0 to 10. This is so the route-finder would prefer easier roads than difficult roads?

Comment: Hi Sam, please move your question to another (new) thread. But in short: yes, it's possible.